# Convert from CL8ISO8859P5 encoding to ASCII in Java

Tags: java, oracle, encoding, character-encoding

probably you may give me some hints what can I do/see in my case:)

There is an Oracle code that converts given hexadecimal input in `AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8ISO8859P5` to ASCII: `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_raw.convert(hextoraw('31383831303891353080853737303338385A5A'), 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8ISO8859P5', 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.RU8PC866'))`

Example input: `31383831303891353080853737303338385A5A`, example output: `188108С50АЕ770388ZZ`

My pain is to solve how can I do it in Java:) Prerequisite: I have no connection to the database and can't execute prepared SQL statement in order to call this function in Oracle package...
I am able to parsing everything except specific bytes `(91 -> 'C1', 8085 -> 'B0B5', 5A -> 'Z')` with the following code:

```
new String(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("31383831303891353080853737303338385A5A"))
```

I've also tried all standards encodings in String constructor with encoding but there were no positive results:(

Do you know if there are encodings in Java that are identical to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8ISO8859P5`? Or do you know some libraries or Java functions that are able to make this conversion (`AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8ISO8859P5` to ASCII) ?

Many thanks to you in advance!

Comment: Oracle db uses different names for the standard encodings than most people. I think in Java terms, you want to convert from ISO-8859-5 (CL8ISO8859P5) to IBM866 (RU8PC866).

Comment: Check by `SELECT UTL_I18N.MAP_CHARSET('CL8ISO8859P5'), UTL_I18N.MAP_CHARSET('RU8PC866') from dual`

Comment: `RU8PC866` is certainly not `ASCII`

Comment: @kfinity Thank you! It's definitely IBM-866 encoding. I'd like to mark your answer as Accepted but I don't know how to do it:)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thank you for your answer! Yes, RU8PC866 isn't ASCII, but I guess that Oracle code that I posted in the end converts RU8PC866 to ASCII with Oracle functions (I'm not very strong with this theme)

Answer (score 0):

AMERICAN_AMERICA.RU8PC866 Oracle encoding is IBM-866 encoding in Java (hint from @kfinity). My issue solved by using

```
new String(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(input), "IBM-866")
```

CP866 worked as well.